# Bulk updating, update multiple rows in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

Am trying to update multiple data in laravel but the solutions am getting when i search on goole are not what am lookin for. here is mycode:

In blade

```
<form action="{{url('users/update')}}" method='post'>
@foreach($data as $users)
 <tr>
<td>
  <input type="" name="id[]" value="{{ $users->id  }}">
  <input type="" name="names[]" value="{{ $users->name }}">
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
<button type="submit">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

In Controller

```
 public function updateuser(Request $request){
     
     $users = user::where("id" ,$request->$id)->update(["name" => $request->names]);
     
     return back()->with('success','Successfully');
   }
```

I want to be able to update lets say i have 10 records in the database i want to update all 10 using their respective IDs

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

First if you want to update or do something you need to provide `@csrf` in the form. If you are doing update or delete method you need to provide `@method('PUT')` or `@method('DELETE')`.

Second thing I am not sure that you can provide `user::`, try `User::`.

**Here is what you asked for**

```
foreach($request->id as $key => $id) {
    User::where('id', $id)->first()->update([
        'name' => $request->names[$key]
    ]);
}
```

This should work fine :)